# ASP.net dropdownlist trims extra spaces while displaying automatically

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, texttrimming

Following is my code.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newLsit = new List<string>();
        newLsit.Add("1 1");
        newLsit.Add("1  1");
        newLsit.Add("1   1");
        this.DropDownList1.DataSource = newLsit;
        this.DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }

When dropdown list displays the values all the values are coming as "1 1" "1 1" "1 1"
```

How to display extra spaces as well and avoid this trimming?

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of `" "`. Your code should look like this.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newLsit = new List<string>();
        newLsit.Add("1&nbsp;1");
        newLsit.Add("1&nbsp;&nbsp;1");
        newLsit.Add("1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1");
        this.DropDownList1.DataSource = newLsit;
        this.DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i just wrote a smaple however my original code contains an entity list.
So do i need to write some generic code to encrypt the List of entities before rendering

Comment: Can you please give more details?

Comment: I am able to see &nbsp; characters in the lsit with your code

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
int num=1;
        newLsit.add("1"+String.format("%"+num+"s","1"));
        num=2;
        newLsit.add("1"+String.format("%"+num+"s","1"));
        num=3;
        newLsit.add("1"+String.format("%"+num+"s","1"));
```